# How to position a window (e.g. iTunes Mini Player) next to the Dock?

Tags: macos, itunes, dock, window-manager

I like to keep the iTunes Mini Player in the bottom left corner of my screen, since it doesn't overlap anything else there and I can always see it. This works fine, with the following exception:

When I change iTunes to the standard iTunes window again to select a different playlist or  browse my selection, and then switch it back to the Mini Player, it's still in the bottom left corner, but is now positioned a bit too high, basically above the dock, instead of to the left of the dock. Which means I have to move it down again.

It seems like Windows have a natural tendency to avoid positions next to the dock, with the bottom of the window at the very bottom of the screen.

Is there a way to work around this, to force the window to stay at the bottom of the screen?

Answer (score 1):

The dock will automatically push windows up above it to avoid the problem of losing windows. This is something that cannot be changed I believe. The only way to get it down that far would be to hide the dock or place the dock on the left/right side.